# Action with 'wildcard' parameter in struts.xml and its annotation equivalent

Tags: java, struts2, annotations, action, struts2-convention-plugin

I have an action defined in struts.xml which deletes a record on the database. However, I would like to map this action using annotations. This contains a "wildcard" parameter (the id of the record to be deleted). I am not quite sure how could this be when using annotations.

The action in struts.xml is as follows:

```
<action name="delete/*" class="RecordAction" method="deleteRecord">
    <param name="record.id">{1}</param>
    <result type="redirect">/table.html</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Annotations are used along with convention plugin applied to your configuration.

Comment: You can use parameters in namespaces for mapping namespace pattern to request parameter - http://struts.apache.org/docs/wildcard-mappings.html#WildcardMappings-Parametersinnamespaces.